# Keyboard accelerators in SQL SSMS to script a table, proc, UDF or a view's definition

Tags: sql, ssms, hotkeys

In the post for "[SQL Server Management Studio – tips for improving the TSQL coding process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101079/sql-server-management-studio-tips-for-improving-the-tsql-coding-process)" it was referenced to use Keyboard accelerators such as Ctrl-0 to Quickly script a table's data, or a proc, UDF, or view's definition.  How exactly is this done?  Shouldn't it be available by customizing the context menus and assigning a hotkey to the script object to clipboard option?

Answer (score 2):

Look at SSMS -> Options -> Tools -> Environment / Keyboard.  There's a list of key combinations and the stored procedure each will execute.  You can write your own SP and add it in here.